# aspnetcore docker and .pfx certificate..HOW TO?

Tags: ssl, docker, asp.net-core

this is what I did so far in Program.cs

```
X509Certificate2Collection certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, envConfiguration["certThumbprint"], true);
X509Certificate2 cert = certs[0];
options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, hostUri.Port, (a => a.UseHttps(cert)));
```

Then I converted my .pfx file to .crt using

```
openssl pkcs12 -in [yourfile.pfx] -out [certificate.crt]
```

then in my Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore
WORKDIR /app
COPY publish-output/. .
COPY certificates/. /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
RUN update-ca-certificates
EXPOSE 5003
ENTRYPOINT dotnet <nameOfMyApp>.dll
```

the build runs good with no errors. and when I run it it was also good with no errors on startup.

this is the output

```
Content root path: /app
Now listening on: https://0.0.0.0:5003
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

but when I tried access localhost:5003, it gave me this error

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Uncaught exception from the OnConnectionAsync method of an IConnectionAdapter.
System.NotSupportedException: The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key.
```